# Insert image in PDF footer with wicked_pdf

Tags: image, footer, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I'm generating a PDF using `wicked_pdf` and I want to include a footer with an image in every page.

I generated a file, `footer.pdf.erb`, to insert in the bottom of the pages, but, when the PDF is rendered, the image appears at the top and the content of the page disappears.

The versions I'm using are 0.10.2 for `wicked_pdf` gem and 0.12.1 for `wkhtmltopdf`.

**footer.pdf.erb**

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%=wicked_pdf_image_tag('image_path', :width => "97", :height => "25")%>
  </body>
</html>
```

**controller.rb**

```
format.pdf do
  render  :pdf => "pdf",
          :footer => {:html => {:layout => 'layouts/pdfs/footer.pdf.erb'}}
end
```

Is the `:footer` call OK? Or there is another way to insert an image in the footer of the PDFs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realized that the problem was the size of the footer, no the configuration. The footer was to high and it reached the top of the page. I solved it adjusting the margin of the bottom. I also changed the footer to `footer.html.erb`.

```
format.pdf do
  render  :pdf => "pdf",
          :margin => {:bottom => 15},
          :footer => {:html => {:template => 'layouts/pdfs/footer.html.erb'}}
  end
end
```